# Adding a character to the beginning *and* end of every line

Tags: regex, perl, idiomatic-perl

I have a line of plain text that i need to wrap in a '<' and '/>'.

So I can do this `perl -pe 's/^/</' myfile` and then do it again substituting the `^` with a `$`

Is there anyway to do this with one line of code instead of iterating twice over the file ?

Could it be done better in sed or awk ? How ?

Comment: All answers were good. cjm got the xtra points for speed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/^/</; s!$!/>!' myfile
```

You can use any number of statements; just separate them with a semicolon.  And use alternate delimiters when your regex includes a `/` for clarity.

Comment: PBP recommends using `{}` for clarity: `perl -pe 's{^}{<}; s{$}{/>}' myfile`

Answer (score 2):

yet another way ( but faster :-)   )

```
   perl -i -ne 'chomp;print "<$_>\n"' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/^.*$/<$0\/>/mg' myfile
```

**EDIT:** The above found incorrect—see comments by @cjm, below.

Comment: Two simple regexps are often faster than one more complex one (in this case, it's not necessary to capture anything).  Also, there's no need for the `/g` modifier; you're already processing one line at a time.  It just slows things down searching for another match.

Comment: A far more serious problem I didn't notice at first is that `$0` is not the text matched by the regex.  It's the program name (`-e` in this case).  You meant `$&`.

Comment: @cjm - Ah, thanks for the corrections. I'll leave my answer up as I found the `$0` thing surprising, and others may too. But +1 to you.